# SendGrid V3 connect using username and password

Tags: c#, sendgrid-api-v3

How can I use SendGrid.SendGridClient to connect using username and password.

There are lot of examples given using how to connect with API Key.

But if I want to connect with username and password. How do i achieve that ?

I am using sendgrid 9.10.0

Any help ?

Comment: I am using  API key instead of username and password

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/How_To_Use_The_Web_API_v3/authentication.html), an API key is the recommended approach for the V3 API, it doesn't explicitly state it doesn't support Basic authentication so if you could try setting the `Authorization` header directly (headers can be passed into the client as options). However, I'd strongly advise just using an API key, it's a much more secure mechanism.

FWIW Basic authentication is considered legacy and should only be used for V2.